# Closed Resultset: next error in jsp page, after upgrading to ojdbc7.jar from ojdbc14.jar via myEclipse

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

Creating two result sets in a Java class below & when return to the jsp page, access it below as such & then loop through the result sets to put data on the page fields.

Was working just fine with ojdbc14.jar, but now upgraded to ojdbc7.jar (for Oracle 12c) via myEclipse project. Getting a Closed Resultset: next error in the jsp page when access the first result set.

Any ideas or suggestions please with this upgrade being done?

I know I can use collections, etc., but trying to keep the code the same with this returned cursors result sets to be accessed in the jsp page.  Thanks for any assistance.

**jsp page:**

```
<%
BCSData vBCS =   
(BCSData)session.getAttribute("com.sherwin.barcodeshipping.bcsData");
%>

<TABLE class="data" >
<TR class="header">
   <TD class="dataTxt"> Order Number    </TD> 
   <TD class="dataTxt">  Rex            </TD>
   <TD class="dataTxt">  Size Code      </TD>
   <TD class="dataTxt">  Loc            </TD>
   <TD class="dataNbr">  Total Cartons  </TD>
   <TD class="dataNbr">  Total Pallets  </TD>
   <TD class="dataNbr">  Total Weight   </TD>
   <TD class="dataNbr"> Total Units     </TD> 
   <TD class="dataNbr"> Order Units     </TD> 
   <TD class="dataNbr"> Order Qty       </TD>                    
</TR>
<% 
 while (vBCS.bolResultSet.next())
 {   
%>
 <TR class="body"> 
   <TD class="dataTxt"><%= vBCS.bolResultSet.getString(1) %> </TD>
   <TD class="dataTxt"><%= vBCS.bolResultSet.getString(2) %> </TD>
   <TD class="dataTxt"><%= vBCS.bolResultSet.getString(3) %> </TD>
   <TD class="dataTxt"><%= vBCS.bolResultSet.getString(4) %> </TD>
   <TD class="dataNbr"><%= vBCS.bolResultSet.getFloat(5) %>  </TD>
   <TD class="dataNbr"><%= vBCS.bolResultSet.getFloat(6) %>  </TD>
   <TD class="dataNbr"><%= vBCS.bolResultSet.getFloat(7) %>  </TD>
   <TD class="dataNbr"><%= vBCS.bolResultSet.getFloat(8) %>  </TD>
   <TD class="dataNbr"><%= vBCS.bolResultSet.getFloat(9) %>  </TD>
   <TD class="dataNbr"><%= vBCS.bolResultSet.getFloat(10) %> </TD>

 </TR>
<%                       
  }
%>
</TABLE>

<HR class="innerMed" > 

<TABLE class="data">
   <TR class="header">
       <TD class="dataTxt"> WHS            </TD> 
       <TD class="dataTxt"> Customer       </TD>
       <TD class="dataTxt"> Dock           </TD>           
       <TD class="dataNbr"> Total Pallets  </TD>
       <TD class="dataNbr"> Total Weight   </TD>
       <TD class="dataNbr"> Total Units    </TD>                  
  </TR>
<% 
   while (vBCS.bolSummaryResultSet.next())
   {   
%>  
   <TR class="body"> 
      <TD class="dataTxt"><%= vBCS.bolSummaryResultSet.getString(1) 
%> </TD>
      <TD class="dataTxt"><%= vBCS.bolSummaryResultSet.getString(2) 
%> </TD>
      <TD class="dataTxt"><%= vBCS.bolSummaryResultSet.getString(3) 
%> </TD>
      <TD class="dataNbr"><%= vBCS.bolSummaryResultSet.getFloat(4)  
%> </TD>
      <TD class="dataNbr"><%= vBCS.bolSummaryResultSet.getFloat(5)  
%> </TD>
      <TD class="dataNbr"><%= vBCS.bolSummaryResultSet.getFloat(6)  
%> </TD>       
   </TR>
<%
   } // while
%>
</TABLE>
```

Java class where the result sets were created and closed:

```
public ResultSet           bolResultSet;
public ResultSet           bolSummaryResultSet;

public Integer assignDock(String pDBSource, String pLoginID)
{   
Integer             vRetCode;
String              vRetMsg;
Connection          vConnection = null;
CallableStatement   vCallStmt   = null;

try
{        
    vConnection = DBConnection.getConnection(pDBSource, pLoginID);
    //System.out.println("BCSData.java assignDock");
    vCallStmt = vConnection.prepareCall
    ("BEGIN ship_door_assignment_pkg.assign_dock (?,?, ?,?,?,?,?,?, ?,?,?,?,?,?, ?, ?,?,?,?); END;");

    vCallStmt.setString(1, plantCode);
    vCallStmt.setString(2, dock);
    vCallStmt.setString(3, p1.palLbl);
    vCallStmt.setFloat(4,  p1.cartonQty);
    vCallStmt.setFloat(5,  p1.palSize);
    vCallStmt.setFloat(6,  p1.drumGallons);
    vCallStmt.setFloat(7,  p1.drumGross);
    vCallStmt.setFloat(8,  p1.drumTare);
    vCallStmt.setString(9, p2.palLbl);
    vCallStmt.setFloat(10, p2.cartonQty);
    vCallStmt.setFloat(11, p2.palSize);
    vCallStmt.setFloat(12, p2.drumGallons);
    vCallStmt.setFloat(13, p2.drumGross);
    vCallStmt.setFloat(14, p2.drumTare);
    vCallStmt.setString(15, printer);
    vCallStmt.registerOutParameter(16, OracleTypes.NUMBER);
    vCallStmt.registerOutParameter(17, OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
    vCallStmt.registerOutParameter(18, OracleTypes.CURSOR);   
    vCallStmt.registerOutParameter(19, OracleTypes.CURSOR); 

    vCallStmt.execute();

    vRetCode  = vCallStmt.getInt(16);
    vRetMsg   = vCallStmt.getString(17); 

    if (vRetCode == 0)
    {               
        bolSummaryResultSet = (ResultSet)vCallStmt.getObject(18);
        bolResultSet = (ResultSet)vCallStmt.getObject(19);  
    }   
    else
    {   errorMsg = vRetMsg;
    }

}
catch (SQLException se)
{
    throw new RuntimeException(se);
}
finally
{       
    DBConnection.closeCallableStatement(vCallStmt);
    DBConnection.closeConnection(vConnection);
}       

return vRetCode;    

}  //assignDock
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a lifecycle problem. If you close the database connection, all related result sets are also closed. (There is no connection to the database anymore. Don't ask me why it worked before.)

So you have to change your code such that it follows this sequence:

1. Run stored procedure and retrieve cursor/result set
2. Execute JSP page
3. Close database connection

I couldn't find any information if the result set retrieved as an out parameter of the stored procedure lives on after the statement has been closed. I think so. If not, you also need to wait before you close the statement.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that ResultSet must be closed too, and normally before the close of the statement. That statement or the connection might close the result set. However there are flags to make the result used longer, and even separate types. However common practice is to shovel a ResultSet to some List, and use that.

Try this:

```
vCallStmt = vConnection.prepareCall("BEGIN ship_door_assignment_pkg.assign_dock"
        + "(?,?, ?,?,?,?,?,?, ?,?,?,?,?,?, ?, ?,?,?,?); END;",
    ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
    ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY,
    ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT);
```

The last option should work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, and will consider the 2nd one.  But, you mention their are flags to make the result used longer ... can you please explain how/where this is done.  Here is a sysout when I create the result sets in the java class, and then when read them when get to the jsp page:

Comment: Here are the sysouts:  BCSData.java assignDock bolSummaryResultSet: oracle.jdbc.driver.ForwardOnlyResultSet@70b37e69
BCSData.java assignDock bolResultSet: oracle.jdbc.driver.ForwardOnlyResultSet@399dd91b
BCSSummary.jsp assignDock bolSummaryResultSet: oracle.jdbc.driver.ForwardOnlyResultSet@70b37e69
BCSSummary.jsp assignDock bolResultSet: oracle.jdbc.driver.ForwardOnlyResultSet@399dd91b  Note:  I see oracle.jdbc.driver ... not sure if this is acceptable with the driver node for ojdbc7.jar driver.  But if can elaborate on the settings.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I just saw your suggestion about leaving open with the ResultSet.HOLD.CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT); - will try that.  Thanks.